# pass data blade (laravel) to react component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs

I need pass data in blade to react component.
I use laravel 5.6.
 For example in simple react component pass data via 'props' and i don't find method in laravel documentation  to pass.
I've tried (blade):

```
<Preview article={{ $article }}></Preview>
```

React:

```
constructor(props){
  super();
  this.state={
    article: props.article
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{this.state.article}</h2>
      <h3>Net</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can i do it in Laravel?
In advance thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please show more code? Your entire view and react component would be better to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: i need just pass data. Not understanding why you need code  :)
Okey. Source code: https://pastebin.com/NDE1Qq5b

I tried so and not working

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
{!! $article !!}
```

instead of this :

```
{{ $article }}
```

Comment: such way don't work in laravel. I think need something composer package or other way

Answer (score 1):

To pass data from `blade` to `react`, simply use `let` in your `blade` view.

Change your view to something like this

```
// Use react to display article
<Preview article={article}></Preview>

// Pass data to react
<script>
      let Article= '{{ $article }}'
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. Did I do it right? https://pastebin.com/DQLyy3j7
Help me please.